# about date_format in php

Tags: php, csv, date-format

I'm using PHP Version 5.5.15 and running php (on my local windows machine) with Xampp.

I have troubles with the variable $time. $date and $date2 are working.

here's the code:

```
<?php 
//include_once('connect.php')
function currencyquote() {
    $from = 'EUR';
    $to = 'USD';
    $url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&f=sl1d1t1&s='.$from .$to .'=X';
    $handle = @fopen($url,'r');
    if($handle) {
        $result = fgets($handle, 4096);
        fclose($handle);

    }
    $allData = explode(',',$result);
    $date = $allData[2];  //ex.: "2/18/2015"
    $time = $allData[3];  //ex.: "1:48pm"  -> New York local time
    $close = $allData[1]; // ex.: 1.3151

        echo 'the $result = ' . $result .'<br />'; 
        echo 'the $time = ' .$time. '<br />';

        $date2 = date_create_from_format("h:ia","01:50pm");
        echo 'the $date2 = ' . date_format($date2, "H:i:s") . "<br />";

        $date3 = "01:50pm";
        $date=date_create_from_format("h:ia",$date3);
        echo 'the $date = ' . date_format($date,"H:i:s") . "<br />";

        // this is what i want to use :
        $time1 = date_create_from_format("h:ia", $time);
        echo 'the $time1 = ' . date_format($time1,"H:i:s") . "<br /><br />";   // this line is line 30 of the code

        //with strtotime:
        echo 'using \'date\' = ' . date("h:i:s", strtotime($allData[3])) . "<br />";
        echo 'using \'date()\': '.date('H:i:s', strtotime($time)); 


    }
currencyquote();
?>
```

and here are the results of the php-jury:

```
the $result = "EURUSD=X",1.1372,"2/19/2015","7:20am"
the $time = "7:20am"
the $date2 = 13:50:00
the $date = 13:50:00

 Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface,    boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Nofrafin\php\downloader.php on line 30
 the $time1 =

 using 'date' = 01:00:00
 using 'date()': 01:00:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message you get most likely means that `$time1` is set to `false`. And the reason from that should be that `date_create_from_format()` can't match the date format `h:is` with the variable you supply, `$time`.

Moving further up, you have

```
$time = $allData[3];  //ex.: "1:48pm"
```

I tried changing to `$time = '1:48pm';` and that worked perfectly. So that means you don't get the data you think from the csv.

I tried to download the same file as you do and got this back:

```
"EURUSD=X",1.1371,"2/19/2015","7:50am"
```

And that's the reason it doesn't work - `$time` is set to `"7:50am"` with a trailing newline, not `7:50am`. Remove the double quotes (e.g. `$time = trim(str_replace('"', '', $time));` and you should hopefully be fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly:

For CSV reading use fgetcsv() function, so you will not have to filter quotes from CSV output and there is no need to do explode().

```
if($handle) {
    $result = fgetcsv($handle, 4096);
    fclose($handle);

}
$date = $result[2];  //ex.: "2/18/2015"
$time = $result[3];  //ex.: "1:48pm"  -> New York local time
$close = $result[1]; // ex.: 1.3151
```

...

```
$time1 = date_create_from_format("G:ia", $time);
```

Secondly:

You should carefully filter the input string for date_create_from_format function.

such as:

```
$time = trim(str_replace("\"","", $time)); // you will get something like 7:20am
```

and then:

```
$time1 = date_create_from_format("G:ia", $time); // G - for 24-hour format without leading zeroes in your case
```

but use the first solution (fgetcsv()) anyway